# Why getStaticProps is not getting correct slug?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am facing a problem getting the correct slug in getStaticProps(). I am trying to get translated slug for the page (eg: about page)

getStaticPaths() generates correct obeject. These params are genearte from DatoCMS API

```
 [
  { params: { slug: 'about-us' }, locale: 'en' },
  { params: { slug: 'ueber-uns' }, locale: 'de' },
  ...  
]
```

However, when I am on the german page ([www.exmaple.com/de/ueber-uns](http://www.exmaple.com/de/ueber-uns)) getStaticProps gives context as below.

```
{
  params: { slug: 'about-us' }, // it should be `ueber-uns` or ?
  locales: [ 'en', 'de' ],
  locale: 'de', // this is correct 
  defaultLocale: 'en'
}
```

I am following documentation from here -> https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#dynamic-getstaticprops-pages

Answer (score 0):

The `getStaticPaths` method only defines which “pages” should be statically generated during build time. Your problem will be wrong `getStaticProps` implementation, imho.

Could you provide us with you `getStaticProps` implementation?